# Alterar classe css de um item já renderizado pelo ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Necessito de uma ajuda com AngularJs (1.6), eu preciso alterar a classe css de apenas **um ou mais** itens ja renderizados pelo **ng-repeat**.

Vi em alguns lugares que **clicando no item** é possível enviar seu **$index** e assim alterar a classe apenas desse elemento, o que me ajudaria, porém eu necessito que isso seja alterado pela **controller**, sem passar o $index pela view.

Eu sei qual $index precisa alterar, só preciso saber **como alterar ele depois de renderizado sem passar passar nada pela view**.

Exemplo, eu tenho isso e quero alterar a classe dinamicamente do 3 (ou 4, 5) item já renderizado.

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in itens">
    <li>{{item.item}}</li>
    <li>{{item.alterarClasseDesseItem}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem algumas possíveis soluções:

**EXEMPLO 1**:
Uma forma usando o "jeito Angular", seria usar o `ng-class` e alterá-lo dinamicamente, assim:

```
<li ng-class='classeDinamica' id='li-1'>{{item.item}}</li>
```

e na *controller*:

```
$scope.classeDinamica= 'nome-da-classe';
```

Mas isso irá alterar todos os elementos com `classeDinamica`, e pelo que vi não é isso que você quer.

**EXEMPLO 2**
Para um elemento em especial, você pode usar um seletor, o que não é muito o "jeito angular", mas funciona:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#li-1')).addClass('nome-da-classe')
```

**EXEMPLO 3**
Uma outra solução mais elegante no "jeito angular" é usar uma expressão lógica com `ng-class` usando o elemento ou o próprio objeto que foi feito o *binding*, no seu exemplo *item*:

```
<li ng-class="{'nome-da-classe': item.selecionado == true}" >{{item.item}}</li>
```

e na *controller*, já que você sabe qual o elemento (usei o índice **x**):

```
$scope.itens[x].selecionado = true;
```

Isso irá aplicar a classe quando o atributo **selecionado** do item seja igual a `true`.

**EXEMPLO 4**
Por fim, se for somente um item selecionado em vários, e como você disse que tem o `$index`, você pode criar um valor no `$scope` pra guardar o elemento selecionado, baseado no `$index` e fazer como no elemento anterior de um `ng-class` condicional, assim:

```
<li ng-class="{'nome-da-classe': $index == itemSelecionado}" >{{item.item}}</li>
```

e finalmente na *controller*:

```
$scope.itemSelecionado= $index;
```

Alguma dessas soluções deve te ajudar